# A voltage source placed in the output of a DC-converter?

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzz5My.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a voltage source(V1) connected to a boost-converter, the components aren't rated(more focused into the theory than actual build). And there is a a voltage source(V2) that is in the output of the boost-converter, what would happen too the circuit? Would the voltages add-up since they are in series?

The output voltage will be higher than 50V(if they do add-up).

**Edit** (Circuit II):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvNetB.png)</sup>

**Edit(2) Motor circuit**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOHnbh.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of boost circuit transfers a fixed energy per cycle (determined by the duty cycle and input voltage). Taking into account operating frequency, energy per cycle x frequency = power.

In other words the converter transfers power - it knows nothing about voltage regulation so, if there is a voltage source in series with the load (as shown on your diagram) it matters little - it will try and push an amount of power into the resistor and this power is dependant on input voltage and duty cycle.

So, assuming the power delivered to the resistor is just the right amount to keep the voltage constant across the resistor (Vr), increasing V2 from zero to (say) 30V means the output increases from Vr to Vr + 30.

Just in case you didn't know, this type of booster requires a control system forming a feedback loop in order to keep voltage constant. Without that control loop, theoretically the voltage will rise really high on no-load and break down the diode, the FET and / or the capacitor.

Comment: That makes sense, what I thought about is when Vr is set to 70V for example, V2 would add up with V1 for the input and increase the output current?

Comment: Where would your output terminals be?

Comment: Adjusted the diagram to show the terminals.

Comment: Did you mean Vr to be upside down?

Comment: No, I meant it to be the same as we discussed(or assumed), honestly, I'm not sure if that was the correct terminals. But wanted to indicate a way that V1 + V2 would be inputs(to the converter), and Vr would stay the same regardless if V2 = 0/30V,however, the current Io would increase due to V2.

Comment: Sorry I meant did you mean V2 to be that way?

Comment: In the way diagrammed, yes. If so, would that change anything from your answer/ my point? Not sure what you meant V2 to be upside down?

Comment: In your question you asked if the voltage sources would add up and I assumed the the load was R1 and that you meant for V2 to be capable of adding but you have it subtracting the way it is shown so basically, I am now confused as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited the question and added a contrast schematic. What I wanted to know is **circuit I** the same as **circuit II** to have this: V1 + V2 as the input to the boost-converter? Knowing that in **circuit I** the voltage source(V2) is in the output side, but it's wired in series to V1? **Or to be specific why is it subtracting**? How would it be drawn in a way that it's "adding" in circuit I?

Comment: No, the two circuits are radically different and, there is a danger that in your original circuit the diode would conduct all the time and ruin performance. Sorry for reading your question incorrectly the first stage. Well actually I intentionally reversed the V2 connections because I assumed you'd just got it wrong by accident. TBH the whole premise of the question is now unclear to me. I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: How did you reverse V2? I find it opposing Vr wouldn't it(Vr-V2)? Also, the premise really was an attempt of having V2 placed in that point and have it "increase" the input voltage(V1+V2) without effecting much of the circuit, **is it even possible**?

Comment: I assumed it was an error by you that had V2 the way it is shown. Placing V2 as per your original circuit subtracts from the output.

Comment: Andy, I've added a final diagram(edit II) for the case related to a motor, where the voltage source is back-EMF -10V what would the Vr be now? Vo - 10V = Vr? The boost-converter would be a voltage controller.

Comment: The back emf, as shown in tour edit is a release of energy into the output capacitor. This will make the capacitor voltage rise.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but wouldn't that increase the output? And that can't happen :/

Comment: It can happen - the capacitor is fed with current from the inductor and the capacitor is also fed with current from the back-emf of the motor - those currents add at out+ and unless the main booster switching circuit holds back the voltage could rise above the top limit of what you want for Vcap.

Comment: That can't be... how can there be multiple currents flowing in opposite directions?! Also, back-emf reduces the applied current due to it's voltage reducing the applied voltage that's what been intuitive...

Comment: Both currents flow into the capacitor. They are in the same direction as entering the capacitor at the top on your circuit.